# How to optimize lambda queries in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, optimization, lambda

I'm trying to create a chart that needs multiple data. This is the code in the repository:

```
var resultdb = await  _dbContext.TimeSheetElements
     .Where(t => t.UserId == userId &&
            t.Date.Month == month && 
            t.Date.Year == year)
     .GroupBy(t => t.Date)
     .Select(pc => 
         new ShowPointingChartViewModel
         {
             Day = pc.First().Date.DayOfWeek.ToString(),
             Date = pc.First().Date.ToString(),
             NormalHours = pc.Where(p => p.IsGuard == false && !taskType.Contains(p.UserTask.Type)).Sum(p => p.Duration),
             OutOfBuisnessHours = pc.Where(p => p.IsGuard == true).Sum(p => p.Duration),
             Holidays = pc.Where(p => p.UserTask.Type == "Holiday").Sum(p => p.Duration),
             PublicHolidays = pc.Where(p => p.UserTask.Type == "Public holiday").Sum(p => p.Duration),
             Illness = pc.Where(p => p.UserTask.Type == "Illness").Sum(p => p.Duration),
             GuardFees = pc.Count(p => p.UserTask.Type == "Night Fees"),
             Total = pc.Where(p=>p.UserTask.Type != "Night Fees").Sum(p => p.Duration)
          })
    .ToList();
```

This takes a long time to perform (the results are correct), so I'm asking if there is a possible way to reduce response time.

Comment: We can't say anything about this. Profile your query.

Comment: Can you see the raw SQL this produces? It is more likely to be the actual query causing your performance issues.

Comment: How many records approximately  are  in TimeSheetElements table ? UserTaskId,  UserId and Date columns  should be indexed for improving performance.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing heavy query within query, as it is shown in your code. This will generate a heavy query that has too many WHERE within the constructor of `ShowPointingChartViewModel`.

Therefore you should do the query of the EF first and make it as list before mapping into your own class of `ShowPointingChartViewModel`, then do the select of the list with the mapping to `ShowPointingChartViewModel` after you finish the query.

Your code should be like this:

```
var resultList = await  _dbContext.TimeSheetElements
   .Where(t => t.UserId == userId && t.Date.Month == month && t.Date.Year == year)
   .GroupBy(t => t.Date).ToList();
var chartViewModel = resultList.Select(pc => 
     new ShowPointingChartViewModel
     {
         Day = pc.First().Date.DayOfWeek.ToString(),
         Date = pc.First().Date.ToString(),
         NormalHours = pc.Where(p => p.IsGuard == false && !taskType.Contains(p.UserTask.Type)).Sum(p => p.Duration),
         OutOfBuisnessHours = pc.Where(p => p.IsGuard == true).Sum(p => p.Duration),
         Holidays = pc.Where(p => p.UserTask.Type == "Holiday").Sum(p => p.Duration),
         PublicHolidays = pc.Where(p => p.UserTask.Type == "Public holiday").Sum(p => p.Duration),
         Illness = pc.Where(p => p.UserTask.Type == "Illness").Sum(p => p.Duration),
         GuardFees = pc.Count(p => p.UserTask.Type == "Night Fees"),
         Total = pc.Where(p=>p.UserTask.Type != "Night Fees").Sum(p => p.Duration)
      })
.ToList();
```

Now you have lessen the round trip of back and forth to the database.